# Capacity Misses in Cache misses

Tags: caching, parallel-processing

Could someone Please explain whether a capacity miss can happen in a direct mapped or set-associative caches? If that so, in  what kind of instances?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

capacity misses are mostly happen in fully associative caches because there's no mapping between memory and cache so that any item goes to a vacant slot in cache and finally the cache can be completely filled and may happen to replace incoming values with existing values.
There the cache misses (other than the compulsory miss) happen due to the capacity issue.

But in direct mapped caches, most of the cases what happens is, there's still cache slots available but the slot which the particular item is mapped is already contain another value. There a conflict is occurred.